# Removing redundant set of nodes using python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list

I have a list of start and end nodes and xy coordinates for each. So something like this:

```
Node A   Node B
  0       1
  2       3
  4       5
  20      21
  20      41
  20      21
```

The above table is interpreted as point 0 with (x_0, y_0) is connected to point 1 with (x_1, y_1) So in total there are 6 lists Node A, Node B, X_A, Y_A, X_B, Y_B.

A line is repeated 20 to 21 so it is also repeated in the X Y coordinates lists of A and B. I would like to remove the repeated nodes from the Node A and Node B list and the respective repeated coordinates in the X and Y lists of A and B. I am not sure how to do that.

Note that the same nodes can be connected to different nodes, in this case 20 is connected to 21 and 41, but I only want to delete the second connection to 21 as it is a duplicate without removing the 20 to 41 connection.

In the end I would like to get:

```
Node A   Node B
  0       1
  2       3
  4       5
  20      21
  20      41
```

And their coordinates.

Comment: Why is there two '20' in final Node A example?

Comment: Nodes can be connected multiple times to different nodes, so point 20 can be connected to 21 and 41.

Comment: Are you saying that each line of your example is a pair?  (0,1),(2,3),(4,5), (20,21), (20,41)?  If so, create a tuple for each line and put into a set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have your numbers in two separate lists,

```
node_A = [0, 2, 4, 20, 20, 20] 
node_B = [1, 3, 5, 21, 41, 21]
```

, you can combine their entries elementwise to tuples with the built-in `zip` function and use the tuples as keys of a dictionary using the `fromkeys` method from `dict`.

```
node_AB = dict.fromkeys(zip(node_A, node_B))
```

Since keys of a dictionary are unique, it will automatically drop the duplicate tuples.
If you want to separate the tuples back into lists, you can use list comprehensions and taking each first element of the tuples for node_A and each second element of the tuples for node_B.

```
node_A_unique = [x[0] for x in node_AB]
node_B_unique = [x[1] for x in node_AB]
```

Comment: And why a `dict` rather than a `set`?

Answer (score 0):

If each of those lines is meant to be a pair then create a list of pairs and then convert it to a `set`.

```
nodes = [
# A  ,    B
( 0  ,    1),
( 2  ,    3),
( 4  ,    5),
( 20 ,    21),
( 20 ,    41),
( 20 ,    41),
]

print nodes
print set(nodes)
```

output:

```
[(0, 1), (2, 3), (4, 5), (20, 21), (20, 41), (20, 41)]
set([(0, 1), (4, 5), (20, 21), (2, 3), (20, 41)])
```